# Will break exit a for loop when called from nested if conditions?

Tags: matlab

I have code like this:

```
for i=1:100
   if something
       if something else
           if rather something else
               break;
           end
       end
   end
end
```

When `break` is activated will it exit the for loop? The multiple `if` signify that a lot of complex conditional checks are done.

Comment: Yes It breaks the for loop

Comment: Sure, thats all break do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MATLAB's [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/break.html):

> break terminates the execution of a **for** or **while** loop.

Notice that if statements are not specified. Therefore, the answer to your questions is **yes**.